# jQuery: Making Dropdown work with live() instead of delegate()

Tags: jquery, delegates, drop-down-menu, live

i have a fairly simple dropdown I build. Here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/K8VtB/

The code i'm using is this:

```
$(document.body).delegate('.select .option', 'click' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
        $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
        selectedOption = $(this).parents("div.select").find(".option:first");

        $(this).siblings().show();
        selectedOption.text($(this).text()).attr("title",this.title);
});

$(document.body).delegate('.select .option:not(".darr")', 'click' , function(e){
    $(this).parents("div.select").find(".option:not('.darr')").hide();
    console.log($(this).attr('data-ajax-link')); 
});

$(document).click(function() {
    $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
});
```

I got some help with this because I've never used delegate before.

I tried doing the same with the live() method. I wonder why this is just not working with live? Or what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the same script with live I tried to do. Just nothing works. http://jsfiddle.net/K8VtB/1/

Can anyone help me out here and tell me what I'm doing wrong when using live() ?

Comment: selected option is undefined `selectedOption = `

Comment: yeah that doesn't matter, this is just because I log an attribute that doesn't exist. Just see over that. I just wonder how to make the dropdown itself work with live() instead of delegate()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
});
```

to

```
$(window).click(function() {
    $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K8VtB/4/